# Display INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS results in a string

Tags: php, mysql

First of all, english is not my first language so sorry if I make some mistakes. I am kinda new to PHP and MySQL and I am working on a little personal project.  I am stuck on something that I really don't know how to do and I would like to have your opinions on the best way to do it.

I want to generate a file (using fwrite) that will contain this information :

```
class applications
{
    private $_"value1";
    private $_"value2";
    private $_"value3";
    etc depending on how many columns the table have
}
```

"value" are equal to the name of each columns of a table.

To get the columns names I am using INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS in this request :

```
$columns = $db->prepare("SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name = '$_POST[dropdown]' AND table_schema = 'tp2'");
$columns->execute();
$resultCol = $columns->fetchAll();
```

To write the file I am using this code :

```
$ouv = fopen($dir."/".$nomfile.".class.".$ext, 'w+');
fwrite($ouv, $text);
```

The variable $text must contain the result of a foreach loop that looks something like that :

```
foreach($resultCol as $value3)
{
    print_r("private "."$"."_".$value3[0].";"."<br/>") ;
}
```

This print_r would work if I would like to display it in a php page but I need to save it as a string in a file. 
Since $text is a variable, I can't use a foreach in it and I really don't know how to do it.

So in your opinion, what would be the best/easiest way to do what I am trying to do ?

Comment: You can loop through your result set `$resultCol` and prepare the `$text` variable. Then it is just a matter of time to flush that data into a file.

Answer (score 0):

**Steps**:

1. Open file
2. Loop through the result set
3. read row column values
4. construct text
5. write into file
6. close the file

**Example**:

```
$ouv = fopen( $dir . "/" . $nomfile . ".class." . $ext, 'w+' );

foreach( $resultCol as $value3 )
{
    $text = "private $_" . $value3[0] . ";" ;

    fwrite( $ouv, $text );
}

fclose( $ouv );
```